# Как сделать вложенную навигацию с постоянным отображением BottomNavigationPage и AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Возникла проблема, мне нужна навигация при которой я мог бы сохранить нижнюю панель навигации. Желательно конечно чтобы это было применимо к пакету [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

В официальной документации на [MaterialDesign](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#placement) в разделе `Behavior` по нижней панели навигации я увидел подобный пример, но как этого добиться там нет.

На данный момент переход по элементам нижней навигации у меня выполняется подобным образом:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    final BottomPageController landingPageController =
        Get.put(BottomPageController(), permanent: false);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar:
            BottomNavigationMenu(landingPageController: landingPageController),
        body: Obx(
          () => IndexedStack(
            index: landingPageController.tabIndex.value,
            children: [
              ProductPage(),
              MapPage(),
              ClientPage(),
              NotePage(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

А для прямой внутренней навигации используется именная маршрутизация:

```
onTap: () => Get.toNamed(ProductDetailScreen.routeName, arguments: product)
```

Маршруты:

```dart
final List<GetPage> getPages = [
  GetPage(name: ProductDetailScreen.routeName, page: () => ProductDetailScreen()),
  GetPage(name: StoresScreen.routeName, page: () => StoresScreen()),
  GetPage(name:CompaniesScreen.routeName, page: () =>CompaniesScreen()),
];
```